# Perform Dougman't Method (Rubber Sheet Model) in Emgu CV

Tags: c#, model, geometry, emgucv, rubber

I've a problem with how to make rubber sheet model from circle in emgu cv , this is my code in `c#` :

```
   // looking for iris

        CircleF[] circles = cannyEdges.HoughCircles(
                  cannyThreshold,
                  circleAccumulatorThreshold,
                  3.6, //Resolution of the accumulator used to detect centers of the circles
                  cannyEdges.Height / 2, //min distance 
                  2, //min radius
                  0 //max radius
               )[0]; //Get the circles from the first channel
        var img = myImage.Clone();
        var img2 = myImage.Clone();

        foreach (CircleF circle in circles)
            img.Draw(circle, new Bgr(Color.Brown), 10);
            pictureBox3.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pictureBox3.Image = img.ToBitmap();
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to come to get your code debugged. If you have a specific problem with it, and ask that question, you are more likely to get help.

Comment: okay, sorry about that, i just a newbie . i think Stack Overflow is a forum where i can get solution with my problem. thanks a lot

Comment: Ok, specifically what is your question? What is it doing that you think is incorrect? What do you want to happen?

Comment: i want to perform dougman rubber sheet model in emgu cv (make Doughnut shape to rubber shape), i can get 2 circle with radian and center point of the detected circle from my code "foreach (CircleF circle in circles)". 
I can get doughnut radian from (doughnutRadian  = first_circle _radian - sec_circle_radian) . Now, i get the doughnut radian and the center point of dougnut. But i don't know how to make rubber shape from doughnut shape in emgu cv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it with my own code. This code return value from input image to sheet model 116 x 360 pixel.

```
// Fungsi untuk merubah bentuk donnut menjadi lembaran
        public Image<Gray, Byte> dougman(Image<Gray,Byte> cit, Double radiris) 
        {
            double xP, yP, r, theta;
            Image<Gray, Byte> grayT = new Image<Gray, Byte>(360, 116);

            for (int i = 0; i < 116; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 360; j++)
                {
                    r = i;
                    theta = 2.0 * Math.PI * j / 360;
                    xP = r * Math.Cos(theta);
                    yP = r * Math.Sin(theta);
                    xP = xP + radiris + 10; //sekitar 115
                    yP = yP + radiris + 10;
                    grayT[116 - 1- i, j] = cit[(int)xP, (int)yP];
                }
            }
            return grayT;
        }
```